# CSS Menu Closing When Mouse-Over Something Behind It

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I have a pure CSS navigation menu with a drop-down section based on some automated menu creation tool and heavily edited.

Previously the drop down was a single column but now, with increased number of pages, it needs to have multiple columns to remain neat looking.

The problem is now the drop-down menu covers my form (where it previously didn't), which is fine, but when moving your mouse over links in the menu the thing closes if you touch any form fields that are behind it.

Menu CSS is probably too long to paste here. Is there a way to stop the drop down from closing when touching elements behind it with the mouse?

Comment: Have you tried setting the z-index of the menu to a high number?

Comment: I added z-index:1 to li:hover and it worked - very much appreciated!

Comment: @user1759173: Write that as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the z-index of the menu to a high number. Should keep it above other elements.